# How to call child node in firebase one by one using next button

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase Database image]

I want to Call my *question(root node)* and its **child**(question number i.e. int )
one by one using a next button.

but the problem is child name in firebase is only allow String.

I have try this

String mCount="0";

then convert it String to int  using
int mIntconverted = Integer.parseInt(mCount);

mIntconverted++;

and then again convert int to string 
mCount= Integer.toString(mIntconverted);

but my app crash

```
// Next Button Code here
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int mIntConvert=Integer.parseInt(count);
                mIntConvert++;
            count=Integer.toString(mIntConvert);
            }
        });
```

java File

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String count="0";
    int countA=0;
    TextView mConditionTextview;
    Button mButtonFoggy;
    Button mNext;
    TextView mQuestiontext;
    RadioButton mRadiobutton1;
    RadioButton mRadiobutton2;
    RadioButton mRadiobutton3;
    RadioButton mRadiobutton4;
    // firebase database refrences
    DatabaseReference mRootRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mRoot=mRootRef.child("Root");
    DatabaseReference mQuestion =mRootRef.child("Question");
    DatabaseReference mChild=mQuestion.child(count);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mQuestiontext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewQuestion);
        mConditionTextview =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewCondition);

        mNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        loadQuestion();
    }

// method for loading ques
    private void loadQuestion() {
        mRoot.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mConditionTextview.setText(text);
                // mQuestiontext.setText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        mQuestion.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                // mConditionTextview.setText(text);
                mQuestiontext.setText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String text=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                // mConditionTextview.setText(text);
                mQuestiontext.setText(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        // Next Button Code here
        mNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int mIntConvert=Integer.parseInt(count);
                mIntConvert++;
                count=Integer.toString(mIntConvert);
            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and a picture of your Firebase JSON structure, otherwise it makes it impossible to understand where the problem is.

Comment: just added screenshot of firebase database. @Drew

Comment: Could you add the whole Java file?

Comment: just Added Java code @PatMyron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        ref = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
        try {
            ref.child("Root/Question/").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.e("!)@@>>", dataSnapshot.getKey() + " " + dataSnapshot.getValue() + " " + dataSnapshot.getChildren() + " " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Log.e("!_@@", a.get(0) + ""); // use your counter value instead of 0
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Firebase.setAndroidContext(this); 

above code is from old firebase version and is not working any more
@rjz-satvara

Comment: use this 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'

Comment: thanks it work with new version with some modification in above code

Comment: oh great.Have a happy Learning

Comment: thank @rjz-satvara today my project almost 80% complete ....thanks for help i have learn a lot in firebase.